# Angular component communication in Angular 1.5 and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, components

I am using Angular 1.5 component model using typescript. I have created a demo component and calling it as card demo component, another component is calling as Card Component. I have below requirement.

1. On a page I added Card demo component using the tag `<card-demo></ card-demo>`.
2. It renders different cards using `<card></card>` child component and repeat based on my json array object.
3. In each individual card I have a link called "More".
4. When someone clicks on the more link I need to load the `<card-demo>` dynamically on the page. (This is same card demo component in step #1).
5. For this, I have created a 2-way attribute called ids. So, the syntax is `<card-demo ids="8,4,5,88"></card-demo>`. So, when someone clicks on more link I am passing ids dynamically to the ids attribute.

Below code works perfectly.

```
<card-demo></card-demo>
<card-demo ids="1,2,3,55"></card-demo> <!--(Hard-coded ids)-->
```

But, from click event of card "more" event inside card-demo I need to pass ids data to another card-demo object on the page.

So, simplified question: How to set the `<card-demo>` ids attribute from click event of the child component of another `<card-demo>`.

Please let me know if you don't understand the requirement correctly.

Comment: Hi Mate, so you have two have the two objects:  < card-demo name="cd1">< /card-demo > <card-demo name="cd2" ids="1,2,3,55">< /card-demo> for understanding I've give them name attributes to identify them. Which card has the "more" button/link? cd1 or cd2. And when clicking who should receive the ids? And I hope they are adjacent to each other not nested.

Comment: < card-demo> has child component called < card> (repeats based on array). Each card has more button, so, the child component has more click event. When someone click on more of a specific card, i need to render the cards for the selected card (A card can have multiple sub-cards). So, I am reusing the same < card-demo> component to render sub cards. Whatever card user selected, we should get the child-ids from it to render those cards in second < card-demo>. Hope I am clear and thanks for quick response.